# Generate all matches for regex

Tags: c#, regex, recursion, fare

For a user selection I would like to provide a list of numbers that match a given regex. The regex itself is very simple it only can look like this *123[0-9][0-9]* or *[4-9]34.2*

I found out that **Fare** (https://github.com/moodmosaic/Fare) is doing the job somehow. see the following example:

```
string pattern = "123[0-9][0-9]";
var xeger = new Xeger(pattern);
var match = xeger.Generate(); //match is e.g. "12349"
```

Unfortunately the Fare-lib is only giving me one possible match but not all 100 possible combination the string can have.

If you think regex is not a good idea in this case and would rather suggest a for-loop implementation that replaces chars I'm also going with that but currently I don't know how? Maybe a recursive function would be clever?

Comment: What would you expect from `[0-9]+`

Comment: sorry, not sure what you mean 123[0-9][0-9] gives 12300, 12310,12311 etc.

Comment: But `[0-9]+` produces **infinite** results. If you know the pattern and if it is *limited* as in your example, you don't need regex. Nested two loops are enough `for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) { } }`.

Comment: I first thought it might be that easy to just have two nested loops but how can I do that in a clear way?

Comment: `var list = Enumerable.Range(0, 100).Select(x => "123" + x.ToString("00")).ToList();`

Comment: yeah but what if the pattern is like this: 1[0-9]3[6-9]5

Comment: What is hard? `var list = (from i in Enumerable.Range(0, 10)
                        from j in Enumerable.Range(6, 4)
                        select "1" + i + "3" + j + "5").ToList();`

Comment: made it work see my post ;) thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd rather create my own implementation than using a library. The following code does what you want to achieve.

```
 private static Regex regexRegex = new Regex("\\[(?<From>\\d)-(?<To>\\d)]", RegexOptions.Compiled);

    private static IEnumerable<string> GetStringsForRegex(string pattern)
    {
        var strings = Enumerable.Repeat("", 1);
        var lastIndex = 0;
        foreach (Match m in regexRegex.Matches(pattern))
        {
            if (m.Index > lastIndex)
            {
                var capturedLastIndex = lastIndex;
                strings = strings.Select(s => s + pattern.Substring(capturedLastIndex, m.Index - capturedLastIndex));
            }
            int from = int.Parse(m.Groups["From"].Value);
            int to = int.Parse(m.Groups["To"].Value);
            if (from > to)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            }
            strings = strings.SelectMany(s => Enumerable.Range(from, to - from + 1), (s, i) => s + i.ToString());
            lastIndex = m.Index + m.Length;
        }
        if (lastIndex < pattern.Length)
        {
             var capturedLastIndex = lastIndex;
             strings = strings.Select(s => s + pattern.Substring(capturedLastIndex));
        }
        return strings;
    }
```

Basically, the code constructs all solutions for the regex pattern. It even computes them in alphabetical order.

Beware of the `capturedLastIndex` variable. It is required as the compiler would otherwise capture the lastIndex variable, leading to incorrect results.

Comment: Sorry doesn't work for `GetStringsForRegex(@"1\d3[0-9][0-9]")`

Comment: sorry, but unfortunately not working either for pattern = "1234." nor for "1234[0-9]"

Comment: @L.B Um, you originally wrote "it only can look like this 123[0-9][0-9] or [4-9]34.2". No mention of `\d`. (And you can add `.` support by treating `.` the same as `[0-9]`.)

Comment: @RaymondChen I didn't write anything previously :) Reread questions , comments and answers.

Comment: yeah, if I replace . by [0-9] it ALMOST works correctly. if pattern is 123[0-9][0-9] I get results like "240[0-9]00"

Comment: Sorry, @L.B, confused you with OP. But it's still the case that the OP never mentioned `\d`.

Comment: @Kai this is just not true. For patterns 123[0-9][0-9] I get correct results. If you take the dot as regex symbol, the result pretty much depends on the character set, so I treated that as a literal, as the output would otherwise be inconsistent.

Comment: when I give 123[0-9][0-9] into the function as a pattern it returns e.g. 123[0-9][0-9]0

Comment: @Kai That would be very strange. I executed the above code with 123[0-9][0-9] as input pattern and it returns the correct and only the correct results. Did you possibly made a mistake copying the code?

Comment: copied exactly your method and also made a unit test for it.

Comment: made it work now - don't know what went wrong. thanks for the solution. marked it as accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

this is my code now working for me. not very generic and only for two possible expression in the string but it works ;)

```
        List<string> possibleMatches = new List<string>();

        string expression = "123?[3-9]" //this is an example

        if (expression.Contains("?") || expression.Contains("["))
        {               
            int count = expression.Count(f => f == '?');
            count += expression.Count(f => f == '[');
            if (count <= 2)
            {
                string pattern = expression.Replace('*', '.').Replace('?', '.');
                pattern = pattern.Replace(".", "[0-9]"); 

                int pos1 = pattern.IndexOf('[');
                int start1 = Convert.ToInt32(pattern[pos1 + 1].ToString());
                int end1 = Convert.ToInt32(pattern[pos1 + 3].ToString());

                int pos2 = 0;
                int start2, end2 = 0;
                if (count > 1)
                {
                    pos2 = pattern.IndexOf('[', pos1);
                    start2 = Convert.ToInt32(pattern[pos2 + 1].ToString());
                    end2 = Convert.ToInt32(pattern[pos2 + 3].ToString());

                    pattern = pattern.Remove(pos1, "[0-9]".Length);
                    pattern = pattern.Remove(pos2, "[0-9]".Length);

                    string copy = pattern;
                    for (int i = start1; i <= end1; i++)
                    {
                        copy = pattern.Insert(pos1, i.ToString());
                        for (int y = start2; y <= end2; y++)
                        {
                            possibleMatches.Add(copy.Insert(pos2, y.ToString()));
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    pattern = pattern.Remove(pos1, "[0-9]".Length);

                    for (int i = start1; i <= end1; i++)
                    {
                        possibleMatches.Add(pattern.Insert(pos1, i.ToString()));
                    }
                }
            }
```