# Get the list of words matching a regex

Tags: regex

Using any popular tool on a GNU/Linux system (python, sed, awk, *sh, ...), I would like to output a list of **all** the words which match a given regex. Unlike the examples I found, I do not want to retrieve the list of the words **from a given text** which match the regex.
For example, if the regex is *"[aA]foo"*, I would like to have a tool which outputs:

```
afoo
Afoo
```

If the regex matches an inifinite number of words (eg. *"a*"*), I do not expect it to be smart, it may crash or whatever.

I would like to have the output in a file with one word per line (or in any format I can redirect to a file). The expected ouput size is about 20K words.

**Edit**

Using the keyword "generate" from the duplicate proposition, I think this question is more a duplicate of this one: [Using Regex to generate Strings rather than match them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22115/using-regex-to-generate-strings-rather-than-match-them)

Comment: Good luck with that impossible task

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate all matches for regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21517428/generate-all-matches-for-regex)

Comment: My question may be too broad and does not relate to the real regular expressions. I just need the "brackets" and the "curly braces" functionalities. For example, I would like to "expand" [A-Zbc]{1,4}foo[aA]. This is definitely possible. Is there another synthax language I should try for this particular purpose ?

Answer (score 1):

Such a tool does not exist since it is technically impossible. In many cases there are infinitely many matching strings, quite often they have variable length. One cannot construct a tool for that, it goes beyond the limit of possibility.